# MSSQL - Can not start snapshot agent

Tags: sql-server, replication

I'm trying to setup a replication, but the snapshot agent will not start.

It tells me

```
Error messages:
    Message:  Data source name not found and no default driver specified
    Stack:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SqlServer.NativeBcpOutProvider.ThrowConnectionFailureException(CConnection* pNativeConnectionWrapper)
       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SqlServer.NativeBcpOutProvider.InitializeNativeBcpOutProvider(LogMessageCallback logMessageCallback, String strName, String strApplication, String strHost, String strServer, String strNetwork, Int32 encryptionLevel, String strDatabase, SecurityMode securityMode, String strLogin, SecureString strPassword, Int32 bcpBatchSize, Int32 loginTimeout, Int32 queryTimeout, Int32 packetSize, DeadlockPriority deadlockPriority, String strRowDelimiter, String strFieldDelimiter, Byte syncMethod, Boolean forceOdbcBcp, Boolean forceOleDbBcp, Boolean enableMultipleActiveResultSets, Boolean useReadPastHint, Boolean usePageLockHint, Boolean securePassword)
       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.TransSnapshotProvider.InstantiateBcpOutProviderWorker(String strBcpConnectionName)
       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SqlServerSnapshotProvider.InstantiateBcpOutProvider(String strBcpConnectionName)
       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SqlServer.BcpOutThreadProvider.Initialize()
       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.WorkerThread.NonExceptionBasedAgentThreadProc()
       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.MainWorkerThread.AgentThreadProc()
       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.AgentCore.BaseAgentThread.AgentThreadProcWrapper() (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 0)
    Get help: http://help/0
    Message:  Data source name not found and no default driver specified
    Stack:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SqlServer.NativeBcpOutProvider.ThrowNativeBcpOutException(CConnection* pNativeConnectionWrapper)
       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SqlServer.NativeBcpOutProvider.ThrowConnectionFailureException(CConnection* pNativeConnectionWrapper) (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 0)
    Get help: http://help/0
```

Any Suggestsions what I can do?

Comment: Are these source and target sql server

Comment: By the way how is your replication configuration? The distribution is apart? Your subscription is pull or push?

Comment: I have defined some system dns pointing to the server, but I have no idea how to name them. I tried several versions.

Comment: don't have a subscription yet, but it should be push